# Wrong output in C++ 32244 segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

```
    //Deck.cc
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES };
    enum Rank {
      ACE = 1,
      TWO,
      THREE,
      FOUR,
      FIVE,
      SIX,
      SEVEN,
      EIGHT,
      NINE,
      TEN,
      JACK,
      QUEEN,
      KING
    };
    struct Card {
      Rank rank;
      Suit suit;
      void print() const;
      // Card(Suit s,Rank r);
    };
    struct Deck {
      std::vector<Card> cards;
      Deck(int n);
      Deck();
      void print() const;
    };
    void Deck::print() const {
      unsigned len = cards.size();
      for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cards[i].print();
      }
    }

    Deck::Deck() {
      std::vector<Card> temp(52);
      cards = temp;
      int i = 0;
      for (Suit suit = CLUBS; suit <= SPADES; suit = Suit(suit + 1)) {
        for (Rank rank = ACE; rank <= KING; rank = Rank(rank + 1)) {
          cards[i].suit = suit;
          cards[i].rank = rank;
          i++;
        }
      }
    }

    Deck::Deck(int size) {
      std::vector<Card> temp(size);
      cards = temp;
    }
    void Card::print() const {
      std::vector<std::string> suits(4);
      suits[0] = "Club";
      suits[1] = "Diamond";
      suits[2] = "Heart";
      suits[3] = "Spade";
      std::vector<std::string> ranks(13);
      ranks[1] = "Ace";
      ranks[2] = "2";
      ranks[3] = "3";
      ranks[4] = "4";
      ranks[5] = "5";
      ranks[6] = "6";
      ranks[7] = "7";
      ranks[8] = "8";
      ranks[9] = "9";
      ranks[10] = "10";
      ranks[11] = "Jack";
      ranks[12] = "Queen";
      ranks[13] = "King";
      std::cout << ranks[rank] << " of " << suits[suit] << '\n';
    }
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
      Deck deck1;
      // std::cout << deck.cards[0].suit << '\n';
      std::cout << "rank=" << deck1.cards[0].rank << '\n';
      deck1.cards[0].print();
      deck1.cards[3].print();
      // deck.cards[1].print();
      // deck.print();
      return 0;
    }
```

I just learning C++ in *think-cpp*
I wrote this code which is to describe a deck of card.

after g++ Deck.cc -o Deck
./Deck
rank is equal to 1 when I use "cout" to output it. I except that it should output Ace of Club.but it turns into 4 of Club.

And it still output 4 of Club when rank is equal to 3.
What wrong in my code?
[it output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMjbO.png)

Comment: You seem to know that indexes start at 0, so why starts ranks a 1 and than overruns? You could have avoided it in using push_back or an initializer list!

Comment: I used the enumerated type at the beginning of my code. According to the book, I add`ACE=1`and ACE should be represented by 1.The other values follow in the usual
way.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes start at 0:

This:

```
std::vector<std::string> ranks(13);
ranks[1] = "Ace";
...
ranks[13] = "King";   // ranks has only 13 entries, here you access element 14, the first beeing element 0
```

should be:

```
std::vector<std::string> ranks(13);
ranks[0] = "Ace";
...
ranks[12] = "King";
```

There may be other problems elsewhere in your code though, I didn't check.

Comment: I used the enumerated type at the beginning of my code. According to the book, I add`ACE=1`and ACE should be represented by 1.The other values follow in the usual
way. It output 4 of Clubs when `deck1.cards[3].print();` it is what I excepted, but card [0] outputs the same thing. In the constructor,`Deck::Deck` rank begins at ACE

Comment: @yanliang that's unrelated, `ranks[13]` is out of bounds, period.

Comment: after that, the card which rank is equal to 1.and suit is equal to 0. print out 2 of Club.       
`[1]    10304 segmentation fault (core dumped)` this message is still there    
I think it works like the book.